# Accessing "this" in Clojurescript

Tags: javascript, google-closure, clojurescript

Is there a way to access the "this" object in clojurescript?

I am [having issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530791/in-jquey-how-do-i-pass-an-event-to-a-parent-anchor-if-needed?noredirect=1#comment22001349_15530791) with event propagation when I wrap an icon with an anchor and try to attach a handlder to the anchor. Without access to "this" in the handler I am constantly dealing with the inner icon firing the event sometimes and the anchor firing other times.

edit:

As was suggested below, this-as is the way to do this. An example could be

```
(defn my-handler
  [e]
  (this-as this
    (let [data-attr (.data ($ this) "my-attr")]
      (log data-attr))))
```

Comment: Consider marking the answer as the accepted answer, instead of editing your original post.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use ClojureScript's `this-as` macro: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/commit/09ff093dc86b455e3090ce3612c5e01f3b5bada6.