# How do I call Javascript from Clojurescript?

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript

I am currently learning clojure and I am trying to translate some javascript from CodeCombat to clojure/clojurescript.

```
var base = this;
var items = base.getItems();
if (base.built.length === 0)
    base.build('peasant');
```

I am trying to convert the Javascript code to Clojure, but unfortunately CodeCombat doesn't give me any error message.

```
(def base this)
(def items (.getItems (base) ))
(def built-len ((.length) (.built (base)) ))  
(if (= built-len 0)
    ((.build "peasant") (base) )))
```

Do you see any obvious mistake? I mostly followed the offical interop tutorial http://clojure.org/java_interop

Comment: There are many differences between Clojure and ClojureScript, so I suggest you focus on one. The ClojureScript documentation shows how to do JS interop. https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Differences-from-Clojure#host-interop

Comment: See this question on how to access `this` from ClojureScript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531261/accessing-this-in-clojurescript

Comment: Remember that putting parens around something tries to call the first item in the list as a function. Are you sure you want to call the string "peasant" as a function?

Comment: I am currently learning clojure and clojure script too. And maybe it would help you. This is how I do what you're talking about and it works for me `(defn get-url [path] (.getURL js/chrome.extension path))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this-as macro ! However, using `def` is not nice inside macro... it's preferred to use `let` if possible!

```
(this-as t
  (let [item (.getItems t)]
```

In your code remove parenthesis around `base`, (it's function call, and you don't want to call it).